# Spring MVC add user to follower table button not saving user to db

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a follow button on a user's profile, that button should add the current user to the database table Follower but nothing is happening when I click the button I have everything set up(that i know of)

So

In the I have a follower service

```
 @Service
public class FollowerService {

    @Autowired
    private FollowerRepository followerRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public void save(Follower follower, String name) {


        User user = MyTools.getSessionUser();
        follower.setUser(user);
        System.out.println(name + "=====================================================");
        followerRepo.save(follower);




    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        followerRepo.delete(id);

    }


}
```

That is pretty standard, I might be losing the data somewhere but I'm totally not seeing it for some reason, not sure what the problem is

FollowerRepository

```
    public interface FollowerRepository extends JpaRepository<Follower, Long> {

    List<Follower> findByUser(User user);


}
```

Follower Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Follower {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}
```

inside UserController I have a map not sure how to map this though, I have a tweet button that works in /{userId}, if I map it to the same url I get errors

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/follow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doAddFollower(@ModelAttribute("follow") Follower follower, Principal principal) {

    String name = principal.getName();
    followerService.save(follower, name);
    return "redirect:/users/{userId}";
}
```

UPDATE:

here is what I have in the view for the button, I'm certain there is something wrong with this:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="follow" cssClass="form-horizontal">
<button value="Follow Me" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style=" margin-left: 10px;" >Follow Me</button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Where's your "action" for the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the "action" attribute on the `<form:form>` tag. Example:

```
<form:form method="post" action="follow" modelAttribute="follow" cssClass="form-horizontal">
   <button value="Follow Me" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style=" margin-left: 10px;" >Follow Me</button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: thanks, but now I'm getting Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "follow"  do I need to pass in the user in there?

Comment: Where is your 'follow' attribute on JSP?

Comment: Oh, I'm still a bit new to jsp, are you talking about the <jsp:attribute> tag?

Comment: You have to add the data to send to the controller. Example: `<input type="hidden" name="follow.user.id" value="1"/>` inside the form tag. Check this link for more information: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-form-tutorial.html